# Discord move bot

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to make a boot that, after entering the command >summon @nick, starts moving the user from one rooom to another, here's the problem:

CODE:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const guild = new Discord.Guild(client, Object);


module.exports = {
    name: 'summon',
    description: "Vyvolá člověka",
    execute(message, args) {

        const times = 6;
        let i = 0;
        const member = message.mentions.members.first();
        const channel1 = message.guild.members.cache.get("689511445519794177");
        const channel2 = message.guild.members.cache.get("774780272738566194");

        if(member == null){

            message.channel.send("Nezadal jsi uživatele!");
            console.log("Špatné použití příkazu.");

        } else {

            Discord.GuildMember.setVoiceChannel(channel1);
            message.channel.send("debug1");
            Discord.GuildMember.setVoiceChannel(channel2);
            message.channel.send("debug2");

    }}
};
```

ERROR IS:

```
PS C:\Users\-----\Desktop\------\----> node .
MilanCXL je online!
C:\Users\----\Desktop\-----\------\commands\summon.js:26
            Discord.GuildMember.setVoiceChannel(channel1);
                                ^

TypeError: Discord.GuildMember.setVoiceChannel is not a function
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\----\Desktop\----\-----\commands\summon.js:26:33)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\---\Desktop\----\-----\main.js:39:39)
```

Thanks for respond,
ancle FIX

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want `member.setVoiceChannel(channel1)` and not `Discord.GuildMember.setVoiceChannel(channel1);`?